# Solve $x^3-x-6=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

> Solve for x, $$x^3-x-6=0\tag1$$

let $x=y-2$

$$(y-2)^3-(y-2)-6=0\tag2$$
$$y^3-6y^2+11y-12=0\tag3$$

let $x=y+3$
$$(y+3)^3-(y+3)-6=0\tag4$$

$$y^3+9y^2+26y+18=0\tag5$$

$(5)-(4)$:

$$15y^2+15y+30=0\tag6$$

$$y^2+y+2=0\tag7$$

This approach, I have tried, it is not working.

How can I solve $(1)$?

Comment: From $(3)$ you can attempt to use the rational root theorem to find candidate roots.

Comment: What... approach? What you are doing doesn't make any sense.  You are replacing $x$ with something else ($y-2$ )which .... is legitimate but there's no reason for it. Then you replae $x$ with something else entirely ($y+3$)... well you can replace one with another but not with both because both are completely different things.  Then you expect them to be the same for no reason whatsoever and subtract the terms.  That's not going to work because $y-2$ and $y+3$ are completely different.

Comment: @SeanRoberson why do it from 3, and you can do it from 1 and have half as many choices?  Why did the OP replace $x$ with $y-2$ in the first place?  Why not with $x= y- 157$ for all the good it does?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do.  It seems you are trying to factor $6 =2*3$ and you have learned some trick that if you replace $x$ with $y-2$ and then replace it with $y+3$ then somehow you get equations that tell you something.  Where did you learn this from and how is it supposed to work.  It seems akin to the rational root theorem where *if* there are rational solutions they are $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3$ but.. I don't understand what your manipulations are supposed to do.

Comment: The substitution which would help would be $x=y+2$, which gives you $y^3+6y^2+12y+8-y-2-6=y^3+6y^2+11y=y(y^2+6y+11)$. This works because $x=2$ is a solution of the original, and when $x=2$ we have $y=0$. But there is no need to work in this way - once you have found a root, you know a factor, and can just divide through by that.

Comment: Oh, I see.  If you replace $x$ with $y+2$ then $(y+2)^3 - (y+2) - 6 = y^3 + 6y^2 + 12y + 8 - y - 2 - 6 = y^3 + 6^y + 11y$ which is divisible by $y$ so if $y = 0$ is a root.  So $x = y+2 = 2$ is a root.  But if you *don't* get the result equals $0$ for $y =0$ I don't think you can get anything out of it.

Comment: Between (3) and (4) to  change earlier approach ...use new symbols and variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guess the solution $x = 2$ by using the Rational Root Theorem. By synthetic division, we have

$$x^{3} - x - 6 = (x - 2)(x^{2} + 2x + 3)$$

Using the quadratic equation on the second equation, we obtain the solution set

$$\{2, -1 + i\sqrt{2}, -1 - i\sqrt{2}\} $$

Answer (score 2):

You can try with candidates for integer roots, that are $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3$ and $\pm 6$. If non of them works then you still have the Cardano formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are lucky.

$x^3 - x - 6 = 0\implies$

$x^3 - x = 6\implies$

$x(x^2 - 1) = x(x+1)(x-1)=6$ and it just happens that $6 = 1*2*3$ so if you set in order $\{(x-1),x, (x+1)\} = \{1, 2,3\}$ you get consistent results that $x -1 = 1; x=2; x+1 = 3$ give consistent results and $x = 2$.

However you need to be aware that this will almost *NEVER* work and you were just lucky.

In general, you can use the rational root theorem that as the leading term is $x^3$ with coefficient $1$ and the constant term is $-6$.  Then if there is a *rational* root it will be $\frac ab$ were $a|6$ and $b|1$.

So that will be $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3; \pm 6$.

If you try them one after another you find

$2^3 - 2 - 6 = 0$ so $x = 2$ is one solution.  So we can factor out $(x-2)$ to get

$x^3  - x -6 = x^2(x-2) + 2x^2 - x -6=$

$x^2(x-2) + 2x(x-2) + 4x - x - 6 = x^2(x-2) + 2x(x-2) + 3x - 6=$

$x^2(x-2) + 2x(x-2) + 3(x-2) = (x-2)(x^2 + 2x + 3)$

You can try the rational root thereom on $x^2 + 2x + 3$ and get that if there is a rational root it is $\pm 1, \pm 3$.  But seeing as those weren't roots of $x^3 - x -6$ then won't be roots of $x^3 - x -6 = (x-2)(x^2 +2x + 3)$ so there aren't any other rational roots.

So we must find *ir*rational roots with the quadratic equation or by completing the square.

To solve $x^2 + 2x + 3 = 0$ we have

$x^2 + 2x = -3$

$x^2 + 2x + 1 = -3 +1 = -2$

$(x + 1)^2 = -2$.  But there are not solutions to that as $(x+1)^2$ can't be negative.

So $x =2$ is the only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers give ways to get the roots, but here is where you went wrong.

You assumed $x=y-2$ to get one equation for $y$, then $x=y+3$ to get another equation.  Either is correct by itself, but you can't use both simultaneously because you don't get both $x=y-2$ and $x=y+3$ for any values of $x$ and $y$.  So you cannot assume both equations are valid and thus cannot take the difference between them to get a lower degree equation for $y$.

As others explain, $x=2$ is the only real root.